# Python | Issue with turning seconds into days, months, hours

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a giveaway command for my Discord bot,
I want to convert seconds into days, months + hours
Here's my code:

```
try:
            duration = time.split('d')[0] * 86400
        except IndexError:
            try:
                duration = time.split('h')[0] * 3600
            except IndexError:
                try:
                    duration = time.split('m')[0] * 60
                except IndexError:
                    pass
        print(duration)
```

Ignore the indentations, they're normal in VS Code.
'time' is defined as '1m' which then I split the 'm' which results to '1'
It prints duration like '1m' atleast like a bunch of times.
I enter a duration defined as 'time' for example '2d' which I want to result that in seconds which would be 172800 seconds.

Comment: What is the problem with your code (edit the question to explain)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because `str.split` returns the whole string is there's no split character:

```py
>>> print('aaa'.split('b'))
['aaa']
>>> _
```

I would do it in a shorter and more explicit way.

```py
import re

SECONDS_IN = {  # Number of seconds per suffix.
  'm': 60,  # minute.
  'h': 3600,  # hour.
  'd': 86400,  # day.
}

def time_in_sec(s):
  # Split by either m, d, or h.
  pieces = re.split('(m|d|h)', s)
  if len(pieces) < 2:  # Did not split.
    raise ValueError('%r is not a valid time string' % s)
  amount = pieces[0]  # The number.
  suffix = pieces[1]  # The m, d, or h.
  return int(amount) * SECONDS_IN[suffix]
```

Now you can try:

```py
for s in ['5m', '2h', '1d', '100k']:
  print(s, '=', time_in_sec(s), 'seconds')

5m = 300 seconds
2h = 7200 seconds
1d = 86400 seconds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in time_in_sec
ValueError: '100k' is not a valid time string
```

This of course is still very far from a robust parser.
If you want to handle input in a robust way, consider a library like [`arrow`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any simple way of doing so? Like, the same way I'm doing it but just simply fixing it?

Comment: There is. You way is more complex, but I've given you the description of the problem in your code in the very first words. Think about it, and you will fix you code. The key idea is that `something.split(anything)[0]` never raises an exception.